# DLLNotFoundException under Unity whilst using FUBI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, kinect-sdk

I'm currently working on my Bachelor-Thesis, which revolves around extending the functions of a Kinectv2 in an Unity-environment.
However, I have little-to-no experience with Unity and C# and whilst setting up the FUBI library (which will be a core of my Thesis), I ran into this problem right away:

Upon starting the Unity project (provided by FUBI), I get a

> DLLNotFoundException: FUBI.64.dll

followed by a plethora of errors from failing calls on said library.

The confusing part, to me: Back in university we decided to use FUBI, because we managed to install it, outofthebox, with zero issues within a few minutes. But now, at my home tower (Windows 10 and Unity 5.3.5, just like the machine at the university), this error persists.

The Unity project and all required DLL's are provided in a single download from the [FUBI-website](https://www.informatik.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/hcm/projects/tools/fubi/doc/fubiUnity.html) itself, which implies that the error shouldn't lay in the project, the provided DLL's or any weird dependancys.
The only thing one has to do (according to FUBI's readme) besides unpacking the zip containing the project is:

> IMPORTANT: After installing the Kinect SDK, please execute the "CopyFaceTrackRedist.bat" located in the FubiUnity base folder or manually copy the "Kinect20.Face.dll" and "NuiDatabase" from the Kinect Developer Toolkit to that folder.

Which I've done via the bat, executed flawlessy and had both mentioned files/folders copied into the project directory.

Whilst trying to fix this, I started manually moving the Fubi64.dll to various locations within the Unity project, but the only result was Unity mentioning it found multiple instances of said dll, would only use one, and then throw the exception nontheless.

I've started to think it may be a dependency thing, but downloading and using the dependencywalker gave me [little to no useable results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S0yT.png)
(I mean, it's showing some errors, but afaik those are related to DW not being updated and unable to work with some forward-dependency-shenanigans or something, according to some other thread on stackflow I've read.)

Any help, or even pointers at what to try next, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spending days chasing after the issue, I finally found one entry in dependencywalker that made sense and after manually installing MPFLAT.dll into windows\system32, Unity was able to load the dll just fine. I would assume it's some dll related to mediaviewer or associated tools, since those don't come natively with Win10, I didn't specifically install any yet and it is well possible the other mentioned tower had something installed that brought the DLL along.